# Trouble with returning a value

Tags: c#, return, formula

I'm still learning and practicing. I'm trying to return a value (total amount of accrued interest) in my "custom class" in C#. I have the formula, but having trouble writing it correctly.

I'm getting the error:

> non-invocable member 'Loan.mPrinciple' cannot be used like a method.

I have looked on line and read what it means, but I still have no clue as to how to correctly write the formula to calculate the total interest.

```
public int getTotalAmountAccrued()
{ 
     return (mPrinciple(1 + (mRatePerYear * mTime)));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line

`{ return (mPrinciple(1 + (mRatePerYear * mTime)));}`

to this.

`{ return (mPrinciple * (1 + (mRatePerYear * mTime)));}`

This is causing the error. You are writing the formula as you are writing it in maths. But the compiler identifies it as a function since it has `()` after the `mPrinciple`.

Hope, it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown what type `mPrinciple` is, but assuming it's an `int` (money should always be stored as ints not floats), then `mPrinciple(1...)` makes no sense. As the error says, you are trying to "call" an integer.

You probably mean `return (mPrinciple * (1 + (mRatePerYear * mTime)));`

As @un-luck points out, it is also "odd" to have

```
public int getTotalAmountAccrued()
{
    public int getTotalAmountAccrued()
    {
```

But I'm not sure if that is a cut and paste issue or actual code...

Comment: Look into the given snippet, is it fine to define `getTotalAmountAccrued` inside `getTotalAmountAccrued`

Comment: Don't you mean double, not floats? Money has a two-significant-digit value, so it would not be possible to save as int. Add up all the times I've been to the store in the last year using ints, and you'll be way off what I actually spent.

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger Do some google. Better to store money as an integer number of cents than as floating point values (doubles or floats).

Comment: @un-lucky. I can see the point for faster summation, but if you get complicated with money, the constant need to convert would be horrible - not to mention that some calculations require more than 2 significant digits. 45Million time $14.432 is a lot different than 45Million times $14.43. Keeping track of which numbers need to be multiplied/divided by 100,1000,10000, or 100000 on both ends of the conversion would be a nightmare. If you're just adding things, I can see it - but in my world of financial analysis, there's no room for it.

Comment: Why not use Decimal? Microsoft intended it for money calculation anyway

Comment: Yeah I'm with you on that. Decimal is fine but int is unrealistic. Not to mention that Math.Log10() is only valid to 9 digits. If you use ints and require 4 sigDig, you're limited to tens of thousands. The only reason you need 4 sigDigs with money is when dealing with granularity in large numbers. 99,999 isn't big enough to cut the mustard.